# How can I back up and restore Chrome in Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, backup

I back up Chrome in Windows with [Google Chrome Backup](https://web.archive.org/web/20120308203820/http://www.parhelia-tools.com/products/gcb/googlechrome.aspx), which saves a file in `.gcb` format.

How could I restore it in Ubuntu 11.10 ?

In other words, how could I back up and restore Chrome in Ubuntu?

Comment: You should probably ask to the makers of that product. It seems very unlikely that anybody here will know how this works, specially as it is a closed-source product for another platform.

Comment: @JavierRivera ; title has edited with Jorge Castro , i just want to restore it in ubuntu.

Comment: It's not the title, the program that you used to backup Chrome, is not related to Ubuntu, not available in Ubutu. I'm afraid we can't help you, you should ask to the program maker.

Comment: Your profile is in `/home/Your_name/.config/google-chrome/Default`. Just back that up as frequently as you want?

Comment: the link that is mentioned is no longer in the air.
404 error

Answer (score 4):

One possible way to do this would be to set up [Google Sign in with Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/more/sign-in.html), this will then sync your settings inbetween your windows and ubuntu computers.

Answer (score 4):

Some settings are saved in a folder that is

```
/home/your_user_name/.config/google-chrome
```

Restoring that folder after a partial crash restored my chrome settings (bookmarks, passwords) to me. So backing up the folder should work.

Answer (score -2):

The question was edited several times, with the final result that this answer does no more answer the present question (the original was about a Windows-specific software), so please stop downvoting it.

---

You can't.

As you can see that is not an official tool made from Google and, more important, it is only for Windows.
So you can restore a backup done with it only on Windows (with the same program I think).

Use official guides to backup your works and understand softwares, not just `some_junks_made_by_unknown_people_that_promise_to_be_the_BEST_solution`.